# What can be reason for the next DynamoDB error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have the next code accessing DynamoDB using docClient in several lambdas:

```
params = {
    TableName : tableName,
    Key: {
        publisherId: publisherId, // partition part
        id: publicationId // sort part
    }
};

docClient.query(params, (err, data) => {
    //simplified for debugging purposes
    callback({ err: err, params: params, data: data});
});
```

The problem is that this code works great in some places, but in the others it returns error. Full callback result in this case is:

```
{
    "err": {
        "message": "Either the KeyConditions or KeyConditionExpression parameter must be specified in the request.",
        "code": "ValidationException",
        "time": "2018-04-05T06:54:28.542Z",
        "requestId": "ELEG6OB4L0RIJ5T4JL3MGUFJQNVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
        "statusCode": 400,
        "retryable": false,
        "retryDelay": 4.5118545729119
    },
    "params": {
        "TableName": "publications",
        "Key": {
            "publisherId": "8a47530c-c1d9-4dc4-95b5-809361ae27c2",
            "id": "019b0d50-37e4-11e8-9972-9997bb75950e"
        }
    },
    "data": null
}
```

What can be reason for that (if I'm sure that keys values are correct)?
I can change the code to use "KeyConditionExpression" and "ExpressionAttributeValues" in every place, of course, to fix the problem. But the question is not about this.

Comment: Show your query please.

Comment: What do you mean? Full body of callback?

Comment: @cramopy I've made changes to post providing more information

Answer (score 3):

There is no parameter called `Key` for [Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html). You need to use `KeyConditionExpression` instead.

Note: I am not sure why you're using [query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#query-property) instead if [get](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#get-property) item since you're accessing the table by a specific primary key, and not an index or an expression for the sort key.

```
params = {
    TableName: "tableName",
    KeyConditionExpression: "#P = :p AND #ID = :id",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#P": "publisherId",
        "#ID": "id"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":p": publisherId,     // Partition key
        ":id": publicationId  // Sort key
    }
};

docClient.query(params, (err, data) => {
    //simplified for debugging purposes
    callback(null, {err, data});
});
```

Comment: As I've already mentioned I use "Key" parameter for accessing the same table with the same syntax for query from the other place and it works (I've just checked it again). There is just no sense in using KeyConditionExpression, Names and Values for such simple situations. They are need for conditions. I don't need condition, I have particular key value.

Comment: I'm very curious because really I've haven't found "Key" attribute in official doc. But I've taken it from some example over internet (not my head) and it works but not in all situations (for example, it doesn't work with indexes). I'm just trying to understand why.

Comment: For me, I'm curious why you're using query instead if get item since you're accessing the table by a specific primary key, and not an index or an expression for the sort key :)

Comment: that is what I really needed! I've missed get method while reading doc.

Comment: Key is a valid parameter in some DynamoDB functions, such as DeleteItem, but its not valid in a Query. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteItem.html#DDB-DeleteItem-request-Key